# 1D classification using Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, classification, tensorflow2.0, sigmoid

I am total noob in Tensorflow and trying to implement [sample code](https://github.com/BinRoot/TensorFlow-Book/blob/master/ch04_classification/logistic_1d.py) that implements binary classification using Tensorflow 2.0.
Here is my source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))

learning_rate = 0.02
training_epochs = 600
display_step = 2

x1 = np.random.normal(-4, 2, 1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(4, 2, 1000)

x_train = np.append(x1, x2)
y_train = np.asarray([0.] * len(x1) + [1.] * len(x2))

n_samples = x_train.shape[0]

w = tf.Variable([0.0, 0.0], name="parameters", trainable=True)

def model(x):
    y = tf.sigmoid(w[1] * x + w[0])
    return y

def cost(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(-y_pred * np.log(y_true) - (1-y_pred) * np.log(1-y_true)) / (2 * n_samples)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

def run_optimization():
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        pred = model(x_train)
        loss = cost(pred, y_train)

    gradients = g.gradient(loss, [w])

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [w]))

for step in range(1, training_epochs + 1):
    run_optimization()

    if step & display_step == 0:
        pred = model(x_train)
        loss = cost(pred, y_train)
        print(f'step {step}, loss loss, w {w.numpy()}')

plt.plot(x_train, y_train, 'ro', label='original_data')

all_xs = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
ys = sigmoid(w[1] * all_xs + w[0])

plt.plot(all_xs, ys, label='fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work. It warns about division by zero and returns `weights` constantly `NaN`.

Got this code from modifying this one for `polynomial regression` that works as expected:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

learning_rate = 0.02
training_epochs = 600
display_step = 2

x_train = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
num_coeffs = 6
trY_coeffs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y_train = 0

for i in range(num_coeffs):
    y_train += trY_coeffs[i] * np.power(x_train, i)
y_train += np.random.randn(*x_train.shape) * 1.5

# plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
# plt.show()


n_samples = x_train.shape[0]

w = tf.Variable([0.0] * num_coeffs, name="parameters")
# b = tf.Variable(1.0, name="weights")

def polynomial_regression(x):
    y = 0.
    for i in range(num_coeffs):
        y += w[i] * np.power(x, i)
    return y

def mean_square(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.pow(y_pred - y_true, 2) / (2 * n_samples)
    # return tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred - y_true, 2)) / (2 * n_samples)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

def run_optimization():
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        pred = polynomial_regression(x_train)
        loss = mean_square(pred, y_train)

    gradients = g.gradient(loss, [w])

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [w]))

for step in range(1, training_epochs + 1):
    run_optimization()

    if step & display_step == 0:
        pred = polynomial_regression(x_train)
        loss = mean_square(pred, y_train)
        print(f'step {step}, loss loss, w {w.numpy()}')

plt.plot(x_train, y_train, 'ro', label='original_data')
y2 = 0
for i in range(num_coeffs):
    y2 += w[i] * np.power(x_train, i)

plt.plot(x_train, y2, label='fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Any hints about things I missed?

**EDIT**
Thank you very much for @David Kaftan. Now it works, I guess.
But is it expected that this alghorithm depends highly on initial weights. I mean that weights changes in very-very-very slow manner:

```
step 1000, loss loss, w [1.2105826e-07 4.8849639e-03]
step 2000, loss loss, w [4.8233795e-07 9.7108791e-03]
step 3000, loss loss, w [1.0805354e-06 1.4478483e-02]
step 4000, loss loss, w [1.9122353e-06 1.9188546e-02]
step 5000, loss loss, w [2.9739347e-06 2.3841826e-02]
step 6000, loss loss, w [4.2620072e-06 2.8439121e-02]
step 7000, loss loss, w [5.7727916e-06 3.2981172e-02]
step 8000, loss loss, w [7.502555e-06 3.746886e-02]
step 9000, loss loss, w [9.4475008e-06 4.1902874e-02]
step 10000, loss loss, w [1.1603816e-05 4.6284076e-02]
step 11000, loss loss, w [1.3967622e-05 5.0613251e-02]
step 12000, loss loss, w [1.6535043e-05 5.4891203e-02]
step 13000, loss loss, w [1.9302177e-05 5.9118662e-02]
step 14000, loss loss, w [2.2265122e-05 6.3296579e-02]
step 15000, loss loss, w [2.5419984e-05 6.7425437e-02]
step 16000, loss loss, w [2.8762855e-05 7.1506448e-02]
step 17000, loss loss, w [3.2289867e-05 7.5539932e-02]
step 18000, loss loss, w [3.599714e-05 7.952695e-02]
step 19000, loss loss, w [3.9880848e-05 8.3468251e-02]
step 20000, loss loss, w [4.393720e-05 8.736454e-02]
step 21000, loss loss, w [4.8162416e-05 9.1216564e-02]
step 22000, loss loss, w [5.2552758e-05 9.5025137e-02]
step 23000, loss loss, w [5.710456e-05 9.879094e-02]
step 24000, loss loss, w [6.1814208e-05 1.0251452e-01]
step 25000, loss loss, w [6.6678018e-05 1.0619703e-01]
step 26000, loss loss, w [7.1692499e-05 1.0983858e-01]
step 27000, loss loss, w [7.68541649e-05 1.13440394e-01]
step 28000, loss loss, w [8.21595750e-05 1.17003016e-01]
step 29000, loss loss, w [8.76053527e-05 1.20526925e-01]
step 30000, loss loss, w [9.3188115e-05 1.2401290e-01]
step 31000, loss loss, w [9.8904748e-05 1.2746166e-01]
step 32000, loss loss, w [1.0475191e-04 1.3087378e-01]
step 33000, loss loss, w [1.1072658e-04 1.3425015e-01]
step 34000, loss loss, w [1.1682553e-04 1.3759044e-01]
step 35000, loss loss, w [1.2304573e-04 1.4089666e-01]
step 36000, loss loss, w [1.2938443e-04 1.4416878e-01]
step 37000, loss loss, w [1.3583856e-04 1.4740647e-01]
step 38000, loss loss, w [1.4240552e-04 1.5061150e-01]
step 39000, loss loss, w [1.4908194e-04 1.5378430e-01]
step 40000, loss loss, w [1.5586588e-04 1.5692532e-01]
step 41000, loss loss, w [0.00016275 0.16003501]
step 42000, loss loss, w [0.00016974 0.16311383]
step 43000, loss loss, w [0.00017683 0.16616225]
step 44000, loss loss, w [0.00018402 0.1691808 ]
step 45000, loss loss, w [0.0001913  0.17216995]
step 46000, loss loss, w [0.00019867 0.17513026]
step 47000, loss loss, w [0.00020614 0.17806228]
step 48000, loss loss, w [0.00021369 0.18096656]
step 49000, loss loss, w [0.00022132 0.18384369]
step 50000, loss loss, w [0.00022904 0.18669426]
step 51000, loss loss, w [0.00023684 0.18951795]
step 52000, loss loss, w [0.00024472 0.19231497]
step 53000, loss loss, w [0.00025267 0.19508705]
step 54000, loss loss, w [0.0002607  0.19783483]
step 55000, loss loss, w [0.00026881 0.20055585]
step 56000, loss loss, w [0.00027698 0.20325364]
step 57000, loss loss, w [0.00028523 0.20592771]
step 58000, loss loss, w [0.00029354 0.20857717]
step 59000, loss loss, w [0.00030192 0.21120515]
step 60000, loss loss, w [0.00031036 0.21380803]
step 61000, loss loss, w [0.00031887 0.21639079]
step 62000, loss loss, w [0.00032743 0.21894895]
step 63000, loss loss, w [0.00033606 0.22148749]
step 64000, loss loss, w [0.00034474 0.22400282]
step 65000, loss loss, w [0.00035348 0.22649813]
step 66000, loss loss, w [0.00036228 0.22897272]
step 67000, loss loss, w [0.00037113 0.23142584]
step 68000, loss loss, w [0.00038003 0.23386018]
step 69000, loss loss, w [0.00038898 0.23627393]
step 70000, loss loss, w [0.00039799 0.23866759]
step 71000, loss loss, w [0.00040704 0.24104299]
step 72000, loss loss, w [0.00041613 0.24340007]
step 73000, loss loss, w [0.00042528 0.2457364 ]
step 74000, loss loss, w [0.00043446 0.24805506]
step 75000, loss loss, w [0.0004437  0.25035614]
step 76000, loss loss, w [0.00045297 0.25264123]
step 77000, loss loss, w [0.00046229 0.2549062 ]
step 78000, loss loss, w [0.00047165 0.25715274]
step 79000, loss loss, w [0.00048104 0.2593879 ]
step 80000, loss loss, w [0.00049047 0.26159722]
step 81000, loss loss, w [0.00049995 0.2638004 ]
step 82000, loss loss, w [0.00050945 0.26597598]
step 83000, loss loss, w [0.000519   0.26814473]
step 84000, loss loss, w [0.00052858 0.2702905 ]
step 85000, loss loss, w [0.00053818 0.27242622]
step 86000, loss loss, w [0.00054784 0.27454218]
step 87000, loss loss, w [0.0005575  0.27664647]
step 88000, loss loss, w [0.00056722 0.27873263]
step 89000, loss loss, w [0.00057695 0.28080705]
step 90000, loss loss, w [0.00058673 0.2828634 ]
step 91000, loss loss, w [0.00059651 0.28490967]
step 92000, loss loss, w [0.00060635 0.28693622]
step 93000, loss loss, w [0.00061618 0.28895605]
step 94000, loss loss, w [0.00062608 0.2909528 ]
step 95000, loss loss, w [0.00063597 0.29294807]
step 96000, loss loss, w [0.00064591 0.29491502]
step 97000, loss loss, w [0.00065586 0.29688197]
step 98000, loss loss, w [0.00066583 0.2988248 ]
step 99000, loss loss, w [0.00067584 0.30076194]
step 100000, loss loss, w [0.00068585 0.30268413]
```

**EDIT 2.** Got well training speed after modification `cost`

```
def cost(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(-y_true * tf.math.log( y_pred ) - (1-y_true) * tf.math.log(1-y_pred)) # / (2 * n_samples)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cost function looks like its supposed to be binary-crossentropy, what you have:

```
def cost(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(-y_pred * np.log(y_true) - (1-y_pred) * np.log(1-y_true)) / (2 * n_samples)
```

Is very close, but has the pred and true mixed up. You are getting error messages because `log(0)` is undefined. Obviously, much of `y_true` is zero, so you can't take the log of that! the correct cost function should be

```
def cost(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(-y_true* tf.math.log( y_pred ) - (1-y_true) * tf.math.log(1-y_pred)) / (2 * n_samples)
```

Edit:
Also had to change `np.log` to `tf.math.log`

Edit 3 (Edit 2 was wrong):
when you call `tf.reduce_mean` you do not need to divide by the number of samples. That is what is causing your training to go so slow. tf.reduce_mean implicitly divides by the number of samples, so you were effectively dividing twice.

```
def cost(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(-y_true* tf.math.log( y_pred ) - (1-y_true) * tf.math.log(1-y_pred))
```

Comment: Tried it. Now it fails with following error: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['parameters:0'].`  on  `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [w]))`

Comment: I changed it right after you posted that because I noticed that error as well. I'm now able to get it to run end to end.

Comment: Thank you very much, @David Kaftan! Now it works! But could you share some lights on my doubts about initial values of weights? Is it expected that it highly depends on initial values of weights?

Comment: actually I think that was misguided. In general that is the case in neural networks (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/danger-of-setting-all-initial-weights-to-zero-in-backpropagation ) but in the case of a single layer, it's not necessarily true. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: you can increase `learning_rate = 0.02` to speed up training.